# Ibn Ezra vs. Hachamim in Regards to Piyyutim

Tags: history, tefilla, song-poetry, kohelet

In Kohelet 5:1 (*Al Tibahel*), Ibn Ezra has a lengthy, harsh critique of R. Eliezer HaKalir and other Paytanim for their poetry's components (in short: flowery language, the use of allegory/metaphor/simile, mistakes in Hebrew, the use of Aggadic material) and their insertion into prayer.  However, the Rosh Hashana and Yom Kippur Machzor includes the statement beginning with "*Misod Chachamim U-Nevonim*" as a justification for inserting Piyyutim.  Based on this, I ask the following:

1)  Are there any communities that are strictly opposed to the recitation of Piyyutim in Chazarat HaShatz or for that matter in Davening across the board? (Excuse my ignorance)

2)  When did the recitation of Piyyutim in Davening become the accepted norm, at least in Ashkenazi communities?

3)  Can anyone recommend a work on the subject?

Comment: Possibly relevant. http://parsha.blogspot.com/2009/04/rav-shmuel-palagi-on-piyutim.html

Comment: Teimonim(baladee) don't have peeyuteem in the 2nd 3amidho n usually musssof doesn't get recited twice but once. Meenyan is saying it silent while the shalia7 9eebur is saying it loudly. They however recite one or two peeyuteem after qarioth hatora. Those who hold strictly of rambam don't even recite those peeyuteem unless they do it individually.

Comment: There is some relevant information in [this _shi'ur_](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/728074/Rabbi_Elchanan_Adler/Contemporary_Halakhah_IV_-_piyut) (linked elsewhere on the site). Try around 4:40, briefly around 8:01, then primarily starting with 24:25.

Comment: @joshwaxman - Excellent.  I'll check that out.